Why apply PCA instead of just removing highly correlated variables? Specially in prediction tasks
First of all let's assume we have variables that are correlated or highly correlated.
When we apply PCA we want to reduce dimensionality, PCA works better when we have a linear correlation between the variables, it means we can predict the value of the correlated variables with a linear function. In most of the real world scenarios we have non-linear relationship between the variables, but if the variables are correlated in most of the cases we can predict the values of these variables using these correlated variables. Let's suppose we have 3 variables V1, V2, V3 and they are correlated, this means I can predict the values of V2 and V3 using V1 that's what I'm trying to say.
Considering this why we don't just remove V2 and V3 and just uses V1 instead of applying PCA? I'm my understanding we only use PCA if we can't remove these correlated variables when we are doing a model for inference purposes and we care about the interpretations of the coefficients of the models, I know the PCA components are not interpretable, but it is a summary of the information of these correlated variables so it is relevant.
But in a prediction task where we don't care about the interpretation of these coefficients would it make sense to just drop the correlated variables and just use one of them? And in this case if we need the values of the other correlated variables or highly correlated variables for any purpose we dropped we just predict it using the variable we did not drop?
I'm not an expert in the subject so I'm sorry if my question is confusing or kind of dumb hahah.
